# Increment or Decrement textbox value by 0.1 by clicking plus or minus button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, viewmodel, delegatecommand

I'm getting error for adding TotalCurrent(decimal) adding 0.1 but getting error

I have two methods called IncreaseAmplitude and DecreaseAmplitude of return type float in viewmodel where I'm trying to increment or decrement the TotalCurrent(bind to textbox) by 0.1 but getting error `Operator '+' cannot be applied to type decimal and double`

```
private float IncreaseAmplitude()
{
    TotalCurrent = TotalCurrent + 0.1;
}
```

```
private float DecreaseAmplitude()
{
    TotalCurrent = TotalCurrent - 0.1;
}
```

I want pass the methods to `delegateCommand` so while clicking on those buttons will increment or decrement the value by 0.1
I want to know how to update the textbox and where I'm going wrong?

Comment: A textbox contains string and not numbers.  To perform math on a string you must parse to a number.

Comment: You need the 0.1 to be the same type as the number you're adding to.  Wpf binding will convert between double and string if you bind a double to a textbox textproperty.

Comment: @jdweng your suggestion worked